# Single Ended Mode Amplifier Problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, integrated-circuit, differential

There is an ac equivalent model of **single ended mode - differential amplifier** circuit. I don't understand how can be assumed to be **Ib1 = Ib2**. Even we don't have a voltage source on second input.
I also added the circuit without ssac analysis.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is quite clear

Comment: _"I don't understand how can be assumed to be Ib1 = Ib2. Even we don't have a voltage source on second input."_ - there _is_ a voltage source on the 'second' input.

Comment: Yes sir we have a supply voltage but I mean we don't have AC voltage signal on second input. It is Vi2 = 0 as you see. My main question is about possibility of ib1 = ib2. Thank for answering.